# installing ubuntu 10.04 over top 11.04

Tags: 11.04, unity, installation, 10.04, nvidia

im looking to install 10.04 over top the 11.04 partition, it wouldnt let. keeps giving me a "root file system not found" error ever time i manually select partition. (i have a win7 partition)
11.04 popped up after upgrade that my hardware isnt supported for unity. 
and i cant boot into it, hangs up on purple screen right after boot menu.

if anyone can post a link to a how to guide or put it on here, would be great?

im trying to take advantage of my nvidia geforce gt 120m (its a laptop) to play around with cuda/c++ programming!

Comment: From partition table(during installing 10.04) select your linux drive(it should be ext3 or ext4), select edit button, select mount point as "/", check format disk. Now move forward. Try to boot in recovery mode to login in your existing ubuntu. Are you sure upgrade completed successfully?

Comment: why dont you supply your comment as an answer so i can check it off, you comment worked!

Answer (score 1):

From partition table(during installing 10.04)

```
1. select your linux drive(it should be ext3 or ext4)
2. select edit button
3  select mount point as "/"
4 check format disk.
```

Now move forward. Try to boot in recovery mode to login in your existing ubuntu. Are you sure upgrade completed successfully?